# How to show more items on the click of 'View More Item..' link or button php

Tags: php

In my web application, user can buy the items online. They can see the list of items. When they click on any of the item, it will take them to that product page where they can see more details about the product. Also they can see the list of hardware parts that are used to make that products. I have limited to that hardware parts to show 6 at a time and then I have a button called 'Show More'. So when user clicks on 'show more', other hardware parts will be shown. How to do so that on button click, I can show remaining parts. Following is the glimpse of my code.

The below code is showing the hardware parts for that product and has a button 'Show More.'

**index.php**

```
<div class='item_display'>
    <?
    foreach ($model->hparts as $hp) {
        ?>
        <div class="col item_grid">
            <a class="itemGridContent">
                <img src="<?= $hp->getImage() ?>" id="itemImg"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?
    }
    ?>
</div>
<button id="show_more">Show More...</button>
```

**controller.php**

```
$this->viewData->hparts = $item->getHParts()
```

**Model.php**

```
public function getHParts(){
    $hp = Item_Parts::get_item_parts($this->id,6);
    if($hp && count($hp)>0){
        $hparts = [];
        foreach ($hp as $parts){
            $hparts[] = self::getItem($parts);
        }
    }
    else{

    }
    return $hparts;
}
```

The above function limits the view of parts to show 6 at a time. Now how should I show more parts on button click ?

Comment: How many parts do your products have on average? 10?, 20? 100?  Should clicking "Show More" show _all_ of the parts or just the next 6 and the user then clicks "Show More" to see an additional 6, and so on?

Comment: You would want to pass in a parameter of sorts, then make sure to use `getHParts($limit)` and set the limit based on that. But, there are a lot of other questions you should be asking. Like do you want this AJAX loaded? Then you can change your method to accept start and end limits, which are automatically obtained, and you append these using JavaScript. That's the most elegant solution, and hits the database less, and doesn't require a reload. How you do this fully depends on what you want.

Comment: @PatrickQ It depends on the products. Some have only 5, while some have 25 or 20 or 7 etc. Also on click of 'show more', it should show all other  parts.

Comment: @adpro Thanks for this explaination. I think AJAX would be good for me. Can you show me the demo(if you can) of what you explained, that would give me a better idea.

Comment: @JohnCaverns, how much are you willing to spend? '-)  I do not have a ready made demo, but there are a lot of resources out there to show how to use AJAX. Depending on the framework you're using as well you'll need to make sure you have all your endpoints and everything set up properly.

Comment: Personally, given that you don't seem to have _that many_ parts per product, I'd probably go the route of fetching them all up-front, and then just use JS and CSS to show/hide the appropriate ones.

Comment: @adpro I tried to find, but didn't get the proper referencial example.

Comment: @PatrickQ I know that's the simplest and easy solution for now, but not a good one. I would like to do it with hard coding only. Thanks though.

Comment: @JohnCaverns, I used to work with Magento, which is a large open source ecommerce solution. I have added "View More" buttons to that system, which already has endpoints set up. It took days to make it work well with AJAX and all that.  It isn't a simple solution that I could throw together quickly. There are a lot of variables at play and you won't be able to find a simple solution to the problem since there are so many factors. It isn't a hard thing to implement, but it does take a bit of time.

Comment: Yeah I understand.

Comment: What is your definition of "hard coding"?  Because nothing that's been discussed here is what most people would call "hard coding".  Also, what makes you say that what I've suggested isn't a good solution?  Isn't good in what way?  Given your limited number of parts per product, I feel that it is a perfectly suitable solution for your situation.

Comment: Further to Patrick's response, a lot of programming is writing clean code that can be made more efficient in the future. We can't always write the best and most robust code the first time. If we did that, we would be thinking too much and not getting work done. Writing code that can be refactored and made better is the goal, not to write it perfectly for all solutions the first time.

Comment: @PatrickQ I thinked a lot and at last thought that your suggestion was best at this time. If I need to change in future, than I can but for now this is the suitable solution. Thanks for the suggestion. i appreciate a lot.

Comment: @JohnCaverns You're welcome. Glad to help. What I suggested certainly isn't the only option, and in some situations won't even be the best option. It's just important that you always consider all the available options and weigh them against what your specific situation.